# Why do we need memory protection when we have virtual memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation, access-violation, virtual-memory

By memory protection, I mean that the following program will throw a runtime exception on many machines:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* my_int = new int[12];
    std::cout << my_int[20000];
    delete[] my_int;
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7A467101A in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002794CA635C0.
```

Because each process is given its own virtual memory, other programs are already protected from access violations in my code. It seems to me that correct programs pay a runtime cost because incorrect programs may access unallocated memory.

Why do computers bother protecting against access violations outside of a Debug mode?

Edit: A good, initial answer to this question is "these checks are usually done in hardware." The follow-up question then is "**could faster hardware be made if it weren't required to raise an exception on access violations?**" Since so much of CPU hardware optimization is about space, I assume the answer is "trivially yes, but not enough to be worth it." How much cost are we paying in the hardware for access violation checks?

Comment: Even with virtual memory addresses, the addresses have to be backed by physical memory which is managed by the OS. Thus, memory has to be allocated explicitly so that OS can reserve it for (or associate it to) your specific process.

Comment: When you have access errors, including out of bounds errors, it means your program has a logic error or has entered Undefined Behavior. When your program is in this state, it is unreliable and usually it is desirable to stop it from doing anything else.

Comment: Consider how virtual memory maps virtual addresses. If the address resulting from `my_int + 20000;` is not mapped to anything for this process, what result are you expecting? There is no meaningful value that dereferencing the pointer can read, not even uninitialized memory to read from.

Comment: Even virtual memory is a limited resource and it is possible to use up all the virtual memory address space without running out of physical memory (demand load pages).  So the OS likes to know how much virtual address space each program has access to.

Comment: *Why do computers bother protecting against access violations outside of a Debug mode?* One of many reasons is  to protect process from one another for example, my programs/bugs shouldn't be able to crash or modify your programs. Or worse if a had bad intentions I could access all your data without problems. And yes there is a price too be paid, but its mostly paid for by hardware in the CPU and code in the OS. (Systems are designed for this)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so do access violations only occur if  the virtual memory page is not yet mapped to either RAM or disk?

Comment: I agree with @FrançoisAndrieux's rationale on this question. It's like if we question the finite universe - "If you cannot imagine what the finite universe is, what do you think is beyond the boundaries?". The program should anyway handle this access *somehow* and "gracefully crashing" is quite a reasonable approach to me. If not, what else is expected?

Comment: @MarkWallace Segmentation fault is a platform specific error state, it is a possible result of code that has Undefined Behavior. When and where it happens depends on your platform.

Comment: Before memory protection, when a program wrote to random areas in ram, you would have random crashers. In early versions of Unix a crash dump was optional on a segmentation violation. You don't want the program to continue when that happens. It can traipse over anything and everything.

Comment: What do you propose as an alternative? If a program accesses unallocated memory, what should happen instead of an access violation?

Comment: Just for nitpicking, it should not be `delete(my_int);` but `delete[] my_int;` instead.

Comment: Executable binaries (executables and libraries) may be also mapped to the same virtual address space. And some OSs may also keep shared libraries once in the physical RAM, and share that same memory for several processes. Memory protection should prevent a process to write over those shared stuff.

Comment: @SKi if the memory is shared, won't that virtual memory be mapped, and so no access violation will be thrown?

Comment: @MarkWallace it may be shared as execute-only and you try to read, or read-only and you try to write. Having the capability to handle "write to a copy-on-write page" means you have the capability for access protection.

Comment: @Mark Wallace  I am just happy that this kind of errors causes seg-faults in my target systems: `memset(printf, 0, 2)`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ might say that out of bounds access has undefined behaviour, but the platform that it is running on will be deterministic.

The system has to do *something* when you access a virtual address that isn't mapped. On non-toy systems, raising a memory protection signal is done in hardware, so you can't really say there's a performance penalty.

Comment: "...on will be deterministic." No: It can be... think of small embedded systems where no MMU is present. "say there's a performance penalty." Not in the case of a out of bounds access but in the time memory will be allocated and MMU tables must be setup. So there is "something" to do which "costs".

Comment: @Klaus we are talking about systems with virtual addressing. And the embedded system with no MMU will *deterministically* access whatever is at that address.

Comment: @Caleth thanks! the follow-up question then is "could faster hardware be made if it weren't required to raise an exception on access violations?" Since so much of CPU hardware optimization is about space, I assume the answer is "trivially yes, but not enough to be worth it." How much cost are we paying in the hardware for the access violation checks?

Comment: Agree at the point "virtual memory", but disagree with deterministic also. A lot of implementations will not guarantee any out of bounds access will always generate a MMU exception. Typically they are not such granular at all. Not every memory region has an own MMU entry in all cases. Sometimes you have to access far enough to get a MMU trap. Some implementations are allocating huge blocks from OS and new gives a part of that block to the application. Access may go to a different "invalid" block from application view but valid for the OS and MMU. That's why we need debug libs (efence...)

Comment: @Klaus yes, there's a whole bunch of factors that influence *what* happens, but *something* happens, and if you can reproduce (enough of) the initial system state you'll have reproducible results

Answer (score 2):

> Because each process is given its own virtual memory, other programs are already protected from access violations in my code.

Not really.

There may be many co-operating processes, and *silently passing garbage* to other programs affects them just as much as direct memory corruption.

If you've tried debugging complex systems with mystery nonsense data appearing somewhere as if by magic, you would also **much** prefer the broken process to fail as early and as noisily as possible.

> It seems to me that correct programs pay a runtime cost because incorrect programs may access unallocated memory.

The cost is implicit in the memory hardware mapping virtual to physical addresses in the first place. It isn't doing *extra* work except on the failure path, and it has to do *something* when there is no mapping.

Since making failure handling faster would do nothing to improve the performance of successful lookups, there's obviously no runtime cost to correct programs that they wouldn't pay anyway.

Note also that on lazily-allocated and/or over-committed systems, correctly-functioning programs will *also* generate page faults. The only difference is that they'll be successfully serviced by the OS (attaching a physical page to the already-legal virtual address, paging in from disk, or whatever). Again, this cost is not related to broken programs reading out of bounds.

Comment: *If you've tried debugging complex systems with mystery nonsense data appearing somewhere as if by magic* Me! I've done that on Motorola MVME SBCs with no MMU running software from the 70s. I would not say I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you learn more about [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [Memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_(operating_systems)) in general. [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) during the page walk, the CPU will realize the virtual memory being accessed is not mapped. The specific thrown exception is system-dependent.
Otherwise you'd have to pre-map every virtual page in the process creation incurring in performance penalty.